I am using Zen Cart and this functions PHP page code needs an adjustment for my use
I would like to have the following statement allow prices to display on the product listing page whether it is a display/read only attribute or not. I currently have the display/read only items showing prices, but the NON-display/read only items are not displaying prices. The highlighted area is what is triggering the display only yes. How can I make it yes or no?
$sql = "SELECT options_id, price_prefix, options_values_price,
                attributes_display_only, attributes_price_base_included,
         CAST(CONCAT(price_prefix, options_values_price) AS decimal(15,4)) AS value
         FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES . "
         WHERE products_id = " . (int)$product_id . "
         **AND attributes_display_only != 0**
         AND attributes_price_base_included=1
         ORDER BY options_id, value";
$results = $db->Execute($sql);

$the_options_id = 'x';
$the_base_price = 0;

I tried removing the entire statement and it removed all prices from being visible.

Is the and in the where clause the only condition added? ... Anyway, I don't believe that is the issue, but rather how the use of attributes_price_base_included is used by the script, as it seems the value of this one determines if the price appears?

Yes, for that string it is the only condition.  It determines if the price is included only when the a display only attribute is selected.  If the display only attributes is NOT selected the price WILL appear.  I did try a fix, although I am sure there is a proper way to go about it, but my lack of code knowledge doesn't stretch far.  I was able to change the AND attributes_display_only !=0 to a value of 777 (instead of 0). It could have been anything other than 0 or 1 I am sure and it would work, I just used 777.   This seems to be working fine for now.

Try to change this line **AND attributes_display_only != 0** to this **AND attributes_display_only != 1** see what happens
